# Zip Outputstream is closed. java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java

How do I fix this exception? I need to add multiple xlsx to the zip. The first xlsx is added to the list, but the second one throws this error:

```
public void downloadData() throws Exception {

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    setSourceList(new ArrayList<String>());
    setTargetList(new ArrayList<String>());

    List<String> tempList = dualList.getTarget();
    System.out.println(tempList.size());

    if (tempList != null && tempList.size() > 0) {

        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        ec.responseReset();

        ec.setResponseContentType("application/zip");
        ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Export.zip\"");
        ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(outByteStream);
        OutputStream outStream = ec.getResponseOutputStream();

        for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {

            outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //zip = new ZipOutputStream(outByteStream);
            // outStream = ec.getResponseOutputStream();

            int id = ownerNameIdMap.get(tempList.get(i));
            String oName = tempList.get(i);
            String fileName = oName + ".xlsx";

            if (petList != null && petList.size() > 0) {
                petList.clear();
            }

            workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();

            OwnerModel ownerModel = ownerMap.get(id);
            ownerFirstName = ownerModel.getFirstName();
            ownerLastName = ownerModel.getLastName();
            workSheet = workBook.createSheet(ownerLastName + ", " + ownerFirstName);
            petList = iOwnerRepository.getActivePetsOfOwner(ownerModel.getId());
            petCount = petList.size();
            createMasterSheet();
            renderSheet(ownerModel);

            workBook.write(outByteStream);
            //addEntry(zip, fileName, outByteStream);
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
            zip.putNextEntry(entry);
            System.out.println(fileName);
            zip.write(outByteStream.toByteArray());
            zip.closeEntry();
            workBook.write(zip);
            outStream.write(outByteStream.toByteArray());


        }

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        zip.close();
        fc.responseComplete();

    }

}
```

My stacktrace

```
SEVERE: Received 'java.io.IOException' when invoking action listener '#{exportViewBean.downloadData}' for component 'j_idt83'
May 03, 2017 11:24:13 AM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.ensureOpen(ZipOutputStream.java:97)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:190)
    at com.fetchinglife.modules.dataimport.views.ExportViewBean.downloadData(ExportViewBean.java:218)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:771)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
```

Comment: Which line in your code fragment represents line 218?

Comment: zip.putNextEntry(entry); this line

Comment: @Thomas you got any solution?

Comment: Not sure. Found something that might be worth looking into... Please see my answer. Other that that, no, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Try consolidating the use of `outByteStream`. You open it before your `for`loop and initialize `zip` with it but inside the `for` loop you assign another `ByteArrayOutputStream` instance to `outByteStream` and subsequently use this one. I am not sure if this causes your exception, but it might be worth trying...

Comment: Thanks. I il give a try

Comment: I tried but didnt work. It shows unable to open the archive.

Answer (score 0):

hello I have this problem, only add first file to zip stream and throw stream close exception,Therefor I first convert the file to an array of bytes and not use stream in zip.write() method, change my code same as follow

```
private byte[] _toByteArray(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        return os.toByteArray();
    }

public byte[] getFileAsZip(
        long id) {

        List<DLFileEntry> dlFileEntries =
            getDLFileEntries(
                id);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(baos);

        try {
            for (DLFileEntry dl : dlFileEntries) {
                byte[] dlBytes = _toByteArray(dl.getContentStream());//output of getContenStream is InputSream type

                ZipEntry zip = new ZipEntry(dl.getFileName());

                zout.putNextEntry(zip);

                zout.write(dlBytes);
                zout.closeEntry();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            zout.flush();
            zout.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

and set to response:

```
byte[] zipFile =
            getFileAsZip(id);

        String fileName = "test";

        String dispositionDesc = String.format(
            "attachment;filename=\"%s\"", fileName);

        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok(zipFile);

        responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", dispositionDesc);
        responseBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/zip");
```

I hope this answer helps